Do we need both [floppy-disk] and [floppy-drive]?
I think floppy-disk and floppy-drive have sufficiently intertwined scopes that there is little sense in distinguishing between them.  Either a floppy disk or a floppy drive is useful primarily in the presence of the other, so posts mentioning either will often talk about both.  More importantly, someone knowledgeable about either will be probably knowledgeable about both – so both tags signify basically the same area of expertise and interest.  The distinction does not matter for the primary purpose of tags: I can’t imagine anyone would want to put floppy-disk in their watched tags, but floppy-drive in their ignored tags or vice versa.
Having two separate tags is also inconsistent with how we treat other removable media:

cd-rom covers both disks and drives in the tag description;
cassette-tape nominally refers to the media, but some questions are actually about the drives, like Reviving the Cassette Port on an XT Clone Motherboard or Upping the speed of the VIC-20 tape drive: aftermarket hardware for the expansion port with "rabbit" in the name?;

likewise the near-duplicate magnetic-tape, which has Which tape drives were the last to offer backward compatibility with QIC-150 Tape Cartridges?;


game-cartridge has no corresponding “drive” tag either; although one could argue that this is because there is not really a drive there to speak of, we do have questions more about the slot interface than the cartridges themselves, like Commodore 64 - any way to safely plug in a cartridge when the power is on? or What causes the glitchy sound when a GBA cartridge is removed?.

If other formats can manage with just one tag for both drives and media, why can’t floppies?
I have no strong opinion on what the merged tag should be, so feel free to write an answer with your proposal – or one opposing the merge entirely.

Well, it's a Good Thing to remind people (especially those exposed to Windows at an impressionable age) that "disk" and "drive" are different things, and a drive is not in itself storage.  But that's probably too fine a distinction for the forum. I suggest keeping "disk" and dropping "drive".  Or we could replace both by "diskette" :-)

But we also have "hard disk" (an ugly term; "disk" is sufficient) and "disk drive", so we ought to aim for symmetry.

[tag:disk-drive] is more general than [tag:hard-disk] – the former can also refer to removable media.

'disk-drive' refers to the washing machine in which the removable medium (i.e., the disk) is placed.  It depends on whether we're more interested in the washing-machine or the storage.   But I refute that 'hard-disk' means only fixed disk; this is at odds with 'floppy-disk; meaning (only) a removable disk.

Are there any fixed floppy disks?

No, but plenty of broken ones.

To me: "disk-drive" or "disk" refers to hard or floppy or optical, fixed or removable; "hard-disk" can be fixed or removable; "floppy-disk" is always removable.

Questions tagged floppy-disk - 217
Questions tagged floppy-drive - 91
With both of the above - 40
Questions tagged floppy - 4
Given that more than a half of the questions about floppy drives is specifically about floppy drives but not disks, both floppy-disk and floppy-drive likely ought to remain. However, floppy must go.

Given that tags are not always applied precisely, I do not find this all that convincing.

@user3840170 On the other hand, FWIW, [tag:floppy-drive] can be replaced with [tag:floppy] + [tag:disk-drive], and [tag:floppy-disk] - with [tag:floppy] + [tag:storage]. Is that what you're after?

It might be splitting hairs too, but it would be acceptable to me.

The floppy disk and the floppy drive are two separate concepts.
The disk itself is a removable data storage medium, and the drive is an electromechanical device which interfaces between electrical control signals and the storage medium to actually access the data.
I can easily imagine questions that are only relating to the floppy disk as a medium (like how is data stored or encoded on the disk as per some protocol for the data stream) and questions that only relate to the disk drive itself (like what kind of electronic signals are used to control the drive in order to seek to a track).
I don't see any reason to have just one tag meaning both the disk and the drive.
Which also means for the other media like tapes or CD, the question cannot be tagged with similar precision about the media itsel or the device to access the media. As there are no separate tags, so the questions use only one tag that is close enough.

I never said they are literally the same thing; you don’t need to write down definitions to point out that obvious fact. Meanwhile, other formats very well can have separate tags for media and drives – tags are not set in stone, they can be created at will. But nobody needed that, and I don’t think anyone needs it for floppies either.
